# DeprecationWarning: Back-references to from Bit instances to their containing Registers have been deprecated

Tags: qiskit, programming

I have the following code

```
for instruction, qargs, cargs in qc.data:
    qbit: qiskit.circuit.Qubit = qargs[0]
    print(qbit.register)
    print(qbit.index)
```

the last 2 lines give me a warning:

> DeprecationWarning: Back-references to from Bit instances to their
> containing Registers have been deprecated. Instead, inspect Registers
> to find their contained Bits.

How can I read them to avoid the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to retrieve the index of a bit within a circuit, and any registers in that circuit the bit is contained within is to call [`QuantumCircuit.find_bit()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.find_bit) as follows:

```
for instruction, qargs, cargs in qc.data:
    qbit: Qubit = qargs[0]
    bit_location = qc.find_bit(qbit)
    print(bit_location.index)
    print(bit_location.registers[0])
```